# Extract values with iterparse() and store in a dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have the following XML code (the entire code consists of thousands of `person id`, which is why I rely on `iterparse()`, as the file is very large):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE population SYSTEM "http://www.matsim.org/files/dtd/population_v6.dtd">

<population desc="Switzerland Baseline">
<person id="100127">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >11</attribute>
            <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >224170</attribute>
            <attribute name="employed" class="java.lang.Boolean" >false</attribute>
            <attribute name="hasLicense" class="java.lang.String" >no</attribute>
            <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.Long" >9112520200003</attribute>
            <attribute name="isOutside" class="java.lang.Boolean" >false</attribute>
            <attribute name="isPassenger" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
            <attribute name="ptSubscription" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
            <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
        </attributes>
        <plan selected="yes">
            <activity type="home" link="220029" facility="home52627" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" end_time="07:49:09" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="access_walk" dep_time="07:49:09" trav_time="00:09:38">
                <route type="generic" start_link="220029" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59229" trav_time="00:09:38" distance="692.895772305751"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="220029" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="07:58:47" trav_time="00:13:13">
                <route type="enriched_pt" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59229" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59585" trav_time="00:13:13" distance="5488.133844246115">{"inVehicleTime":720.0,"transferTime":73.0,"accessStopIndex":1,"egressStopindex":11,"transitRouteId":"97574868-1_240825","transitLineId":"100110001:1","departureId":"97593123-1_240438_07:58:00"}</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="220029" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="transit_walk" dep_time="08:12:00" trav_time="00:00:32">
                <route type="generic" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59585" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59627" trav_time="00:00:32" distance="39.422182688315836"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="pt_StopPoint:59585" x="652159.1523468373" y="6862257.098785016" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="08:12:32" trav_time="00:17:27">
                <route type="enriched_pt" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59627" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59624" trav_time="00:17:27" distance="5813.159959644434">{"inVehicleTime":960.0,"transferTime":87.14818109307089,"accessStopIndex":12,"egressStopindex":25,"transitRouteId":"95327450-1_295653","transitLineId":"100110004:4","departureId":"95327497-1_295565_07:59:00"}</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="pt_StopPoint:59585" x="652159.1523468373" y="6862257.098785016" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="egress_walk" dep_time="08:30:00" trav_time="00:11:54">
                <route type="generic" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59624" end_link="178690" trav_time="00:11:54" distance="856.0619451133888"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="education" link="178690" facility="16842" x="651100.0" y="6858204.3" start_time="08:19:09" end_time="17:49:09" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="access_walk" dep_time="17:49:09" trav_time="00:04:22">
                <route type="generic" start_link="178690" end_link="1185" trav_time="00:04:22" distance="313.6764640548623"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="178690" x="651100.0" y="6858204.3" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="17:53:31" trav_time="00:05:29">
                <route type="enriched_pt" start_link="1185" end_link="413156" trav_time="00:05:29" distance="1302.0939972036185">{"inVehicleTime":300.0,"transferTime":29.0,"accessStopIndex":0,"egressStopindex":4,"transitRouteId":"95450970-1_205771","transitLineId":"100100088:88","departureId":"95450972-1_205754_17:54:00"}</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="178690" x="651100.0" y="6858204.3" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="transit_walk" dep_time="17:59:00" trav_time="00:01:41">
                <route type="generic" start_link="413156" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59547" trav_time="00:01:41" distance="122.21107200064658"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="413156" x="651043.1290909288" y="6859441.216973967" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="18:00:41" trav_time="00:18:18">
                <route type="enriched_pt" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59547" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59244" trav_time="00:18:18" distance="7166.081827475872">{"inVehicleTime":1080.0,"transferTime":18.15743999946426,"accessStopIndex":13,"egressStopindex":27,"transitRouteId":"93653132-1_291567","transitLineId":"100110006:6","departureId":"93653147-1_291586_17:45:00"}</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="413156" x="651043.1290909288" y="6859441.216973967" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="transit_walk" dep_time="18:19:00" trav_time="00:00:39">
                <route type="generic" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59244" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59236" trav_time="00:00:39" distance="46.97102023296232"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="pt_StopPoint:59244" x="648272.9101174484" y="6863974.735813766" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="pt" dep_time="18:19:39" trav_time="00:03:20">
                <route type="enriched_pt" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59236" end_link="pt_StopPoint:59229" trav_time="00:03:20" distance="1073.5096075636977">{"inVehicleTime":180.0,"transferTime":20.857483139203396,"accessStopIndex":16,"egressStopindex":18,"transitRouteId":"97575531-1_238697","transitLineId":"100110001:1","departureId":"97575477-1_238631_17:57:00"}</route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="pt interaction" link="pt_StopPoint:59244" x="648272.9101174484" y="6863974.735813766" max_dur="00:00:00" >
            </activity>
            <leg mode="egress_walk" dep_time="18:23:00" trav_time="00:09:38">
                <route type="generic" start_link="pt_StopPoint:59229" end_link="220029" trav_time="00:09:38" distance="692.895772305751"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="home" link="220029" facility="home52627" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" start_time="18:19:09" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
        </plan>

    </person>

    <person id="100128">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >11</attribute>
            <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >224170</attribute>
            <attribute name="employed" class="java.lang.Boolean" >false</attribute>
            <attribute name="hasLicense" class="java.lang.String" >no</attribute>
            <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.Long" >1140500200003</attribute>
            <attribute name="isOutside" class="java.lang.Boolean" >false</attribute>
            <attribute name="isPassenger" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
            <attribute name="ptSubscription" class="java.lang.Boolean" >false</attribute>
            <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
        </attributes>
        <plan selected="yes">
            <activity type="home" link="220029" facility="home52627" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" end_time="07:43:26" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="walk" dep_time="07:43:26" trav_time="00:58:35">
                <route type="generic" start_link="220029" end_link="624543" trav_time="00:58:35" distance="4218.5741465571855"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="education" link="624543" facility="34450" x="650799.2" y="6865103.7" start_time="07:48:26" end_time="15:33:26" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
            <leg mode="walk" dep_time="15:33:26" trav_time="00:58:35">
                <route type="generic" start_link="624543" end_link="220029" trav_time="00:58:35" distance="4218.5741465571855"></route>
            </leg>
            <activity type="home" link="220029" facility="home52627" x="647557.28056" y="6864961.034271" start_time="15:43:26" >
                <attributes>
                    <attribute name="innerParis" class="java.lang.Boolean" >true</attribute>
                </attributes>
            </activity>
        </plan>

    </person>
</population>
```

What I want is a table with all the `x` and `y` values for the activities of `type="home"`. Therefore the two rows should be X and Y and the columns have the values which appear when the activity type is home (it can also be transposed if that makes it easier to code).

This is my unsuccessful approach. I struggle to add both x and y into the output. The code like this is not working. It is an adapted version of a code snipet which I have used to extract other information:

```
import gzip
import io
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



tree = ET.iterparse(gzip.open('paris_cut_entd_1pm/paris_population.xml.gz', 'r'))
em_champs = defaultdict(list)
for xml_event, elem in tree:
        attributes = elem.attrib
        if elem.tag == 'activity' \
        and attributes['type'] == 'home' :
             em_champs.append(attributes['x'])
        elem.clear()
em_champs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(em_champs, orient='index')
em_champs
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: "which is why I rely on parsing". Do you mean that you rely on `iterparse()` because the file is large?

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing that out. I will edit it now

Comment: i'm getting this error when i try to parse ur shared data : `ExpatError: junk after document element: line 89, column 0` any reason why

Comment: There is no root element that wraps the two `person` elements.

Comment: i guessed as much, had to be sure as xml is not my strong suit. I'll take a chunk and work with then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at it, using tools I'm a bit more familiar with: [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) and [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict). jmespath allows you to traverse json data, while xmltodict converts XML to a JSON-like data, which is easier to work with.

Also, I wrapped the shared data with `<root></root>`, as I was getting an error, which @mzjn kindly explained.

```
#parse data to json-like spec:
 box = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)

#create a specification to extract the data
#the data flows from root to person,steps into a list, then plan to activity, 
#another list, and then our x and y data, which has to be filtered via the type key
#and here comes the jmespath, which I hope should be clear 
#where there are directory keys, you append via dots
#where there is an intermediary list, you use either [] or [*]
#and for the filter, you pass the key into the [] and type in the condition
expression = jmespath.compile('root.person[].plan.activity[?"@type"==`home`].["@x","@y"]')
coords = expression.search(box)

[[['647557.28056', '6864961.034271'], ['647557.28056', '6864961.034271']],
[['647557.28056', '6864961.034271'], ['647557.28056', '6864961.034271']]]

#you can read in your data from here
```